# Quartz.NET host restarts when a job is fired

Tags: c#, console-application, .net-6.0, quartz.net

I have a Quartz.NET hosted service running on a .NET 6 console app. It's using `Quartz.Extensions.Hosting` version 3.6.2.

I can schedule and run the jobs locally on my laptop successfully without any problem. But when it is deployed in a docker container in the production environment, the jobs are fired at their scheduled time but exactly after 11 seconds later, the entire .NET console  app restarts. No exception is logged as if the previously running service vanished into thin air. However, one job out of 7 scheduled jobs runs to completion without issues though. Here is the `IJob` implementation for one of jobs:

DailyEmailJob.cs

```cs
[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
public class DailyEmailJob : IJob 
{
  private readonly ILogger<DailyEmailJob> _logger;

  public DailyEmailJob(ILogger<DailyEmailJob> logger)
  {
    _logger = logger; 
  }

  public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
  {
     try 
     {
       _logger.LogInformation("DailyEmailJob is starting");
    
       //Send emails

       _logger.LogInformation("DailyEmailJob is completed");
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
       _logger.LogError(ex, "DailyEmailJob failed");
     }
  } 
}
```

The service logs the `DailyEmailJob is starting` message before completely restarting the console app without throwing any exceptions even at .NET level. If there are issues with the email logic, I would expect the catch block to log why but nothing is in the log.

Any ideas why this would be happening?